# Extracting a Dictionary<TKey, double> from a Dictionary<TKey, string> instance

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics

I have a generic Dictionary where TValue is of type `String` (`Dictionary<int, string>`). I chose to use string as the value type because the data was loaded from an Xml file where the source values can be character or numeric data types (I suppose `Object` would've been an acceptable TValue type too, but even then this question would be equally applicable).

The character data types also have importance, so excluding them outright isn't an option.

I'd like to extract a subset of this `Dictionary<int, double>`. In other words, I'd like the subset of the dictionary where the values are numeric.

Right now I'm doing it like this:

```
Dictionary<int, string> myDictionary;
// Do some loading.
var numericData = myDictionary.Where(kvp => Double.TryParse(kvp.Value, out temp)
```

This approach is awfully ugly and doesn't get me the result as a `Dictionary<int, double>` Can anyone offer other ways to improve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Apart from the missing semicolon, I don't find it ugly at all. What is the issue you have with it?

Comment: @RedFilter: I have a correctness issue with it - that's not going to work :)

Comment: Your code will bomb miserably at runtime. You can't cast `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, string>>` to `Dictionary<int, double>`, even if you've restricted to those pairs where the `Value` is parseable to a `double`. At a minimum, you'll need to call `ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => Double.Parse(kvp.Value))`.

Comment: @JonSkeet I thought the cast looked funny, but he said he is currently using it :). Lazy on my part.

Comment: I realized I'd set up the InvalidCastException after I posted. Will revise so that the actual focus of the question isn't split by that error. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you've given is not only ugly - it will fail with an `InvalidCastException` at execution time. I suspect you actually want:

```
var numericData = myDictionary
        .Select(kvp => {
                    double value;
                    return new { kvp.Key,
                        Value = double.TryParse(kvp.Value, out value) 
                                   ? value : (double?) null
                    };
               })
        .Where(pair => pair.Value != null)
        .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value.Value);
```

And yes, that's ugly - but:

- It avoids parsing the value more than once
- It avoids putting side-effects in your query

You can make it slightly cleaner but less efficient if you're happy to parse twice:

```
var numericData = myDictionary
       .Where(kvp => { double tmp; return double.TryParse(kvp.Value, out tmp); })
       .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => double.Parse(pair.Value));
```

Or (more cleanly) you could create a separate method:

```
public static double? TryParseNullableDouble(string text)
{
    double value;
    return double.TryParse(text, out value) ? value : (double?) null;
}
```

Then the first version becomes:

```
var numericData = myDictionary
        .Select(kvp => new { kvp.Key, TryParseNullableDouble(kvp.Value) })
        .Where(pair => pair.Value != null)
        .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value.Value);
```

Comment: but weren't nullables introduced in the same version as TryParse (v2)?

Comment: @vc74: Yup... but it's possible that they came along after the BCL team had written `TryParse`...

Comment: You may have already been thinking ahead to the second approach when you wrote the first because it doesn't work as written. You'd have to append `: (double?) null` to the end of line 5 (as you did in your TryParseNullableDouble method). Other than that it's great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a new dictionary using the `temp` variable which contains the double value - this exploits the fact that the enumeration and addition to the dictionary is done item by item so temp contains the correct double value:

```
double temp = 0;
var numDict = myDictionary.Where(kvp => Double.TryParse(kvp.Value, out temp))
                          .ToDictionary( x=> x.Key, x=> temp);
```

Comment: had just `temp` instead of `x=> temp` for item to value lambda - fixed